# FileNotFoundException on working files url

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

So i get in this random `FileNotFoundException`, once in a while when i try to download files
from Amazon S3 bucket or dropbox generated urls. Even thou the urls of the files work in browser w/o problems, in the app it seems that the download client throws the `FileNotFoundException` every now and then:

Here is the code I use:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + startPos + "-"    + dwnInfo.getStopRange());
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");          
connection.connect();

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Some of the properties where added by reading other post regarding same issues, but the error still stays.

Am I missing something ?

Edit: forgot to mention that this doesn't happen instantly, it only happens when i try to download the "X" chunk of the file, stated with the range. I checked the start/end range and its fine. For the first "N" chunks it works fine. (N is random cuz it doesnt happen to the same chunk every time).

Comment: well yes, but the link works fine in browser. I tried using getErrorStream(), but it only skips the chunk with the problem and my file is not created correctly, because it has data missing

Comment: not optim, but i resolved it for now with httpclient.